# How to convert rows with unicode data to latin-1 encoded csv data on Py2 and Py3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to convert a nested list containing Unicode values to latin-1 encoded csv (so that I can transfer the result in a web response and have the end user's local Excel open the file).

We're transitioning to Py3, so preferably the same code needs to work for both Py2 and Py3 (for maintenance and coverage reasons).

Our Python 2 code that works (for py2):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

def rows_to_csv_data(rows):
    rows = [[col.encode('latin-1') for col in row] for row in rows]
    buf = StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(buf)
    writer.writerows(rows)
    return buf.getvalue()
```

A simple test case:

```
def test_rows_to_csv_data():
    rows = [
        [u'helloæ', u'worldø']
    ]
    binary_data = rows_to_csv_data(rows)
    assert binary_data == u"helloæ,worldø\r\n".encode('latin-1')

    # Update: the data is never written to a file, but sent with a web response:
    response = http.HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=hello.csv'
    response.write(binary_data)
    assert response.serialize() == b'Content-Type: text/csv\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=hello.csv\r\n\r\nhello\xe6,world\xf8\r\n'
```

I couldn't find any convenient way to do this using the future or six libraries.

Using `from io import StringIO` gives me (Py3):

```
Expected :b'hello\xe6,world\xf8\r\n'
Actual   :b'hello\\xe6',b'world\\xf8'\r\n
```

and Py2:

```
>       writer.writerows(rows)
E       TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

Using `from io import BytesIO as StringIO` works for Py2, but Py3 gives:

```
rows = [[b'hello\xe6', b'world\xf8']]

    def rows_to_csv_data(rows):
        rows = [[col.encode('latin-1') for col in row] for row in rows]
        buf = StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(buf)
>       writer.writerows(rows)
E       TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

which is an error message I don't understand in this context...

Is it possible to write a single function that works for both Pythons, or do I need a completely separate function for Py3?

Comment: Hold on a minute. You want a function that takes a list of lists of unicode as input, and ***returns*** CSV text? That sounds like a bad idea to me. CSV writing is different in py3 and py2 - in py3 you need to open the file with `newline=''` and in py2 you need to open it in binary mode. If you have a function that *returns* a CSV string, you still mess up later when you actually write that string to a file.

Comment: @Aran-Fey the string will never be written to file, but included in a Django HttpResponse object. ..and to be very pedantic.. it returns latin-1 encoded binary data representing comma separated values (which is the exact format the local Excel accepts).

Comment: @Aran-Fey I've updated the test with the intended use case.

Comment: `csv` module in Python 3 uses Unicode strings for input.  `csv` module in Python  2 uses byte strings for input.  They aren't very compatible, but the third-party `unicodecsv` module for Python 2 is closer to Python 3's use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an illustation of the differences between Python 2 and 3 that passes your test.  Tested on Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.

```
#!coding:utf8
import io
import csv
import sys

def rows_to_csv_data(rows):
    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
        rows = [[col.encode('latin1') for col in row] for row in rows]
        buf = io.BytesIO()
    else:
        buf = io.StringIO(newline='')

    writer = csv.writer(buf)
    writer.writerows(rows)

    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
        return buf.getvalue()
    else:
        return buf.getvalue().encode('latin1')

def test_rows_to_csv_data():
    rows = [[u'helloæ', u'worldø']]
    binary_data = rows_to_csv_data(rows)
    assert binary_data == u"helloæ,worldø\r\n".encode('latin-1')

test_rows_to_csv_data()
```

Comment: Note that this'll crash in python2 if `rows` contains any non-strings (i.e. numbers). You may want to make that str->bytes conversion a bit more robust.

Comment: @Aran Note that was the OP’s original code. It wasn’t part of the question.

Comment: @Aran-Fey my real str->bytes conversion code handles "all-the-cases", but it seemed orthogonal to the question so I left it out. Good point though :-)